# Docker - Share commands between containers

Tags: docker

I'm trying to dockerize my Laravel app. In my local machine i have Mysql and MongoDB.

I have a script that run `mysql` restore and `mongorestore` to restore a production db.

In local environment i don't have problems because mysql and mongodb are installed locally.

Now, i created a `docker-compose.yml` with the build instructions:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile.dev
    image: laravel-docker
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /srv/app/vendor
      - .:/srv/app
    links:
      - mariadb
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_USER=root
  mongo:
    image: mongo
```

All works fine but i need to run `mysql` command from `app` container (that should call `mysql` command in mariadb container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install a **MySQL client** in your *app* container.

Add something like this in your Dockerfile :

```
apt-get install mysql-client
```

Then you should be able to connect to your MySql server from your *app* container using the service name if they belong to the same network :

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -h mariadb
```

Comment: I'm trying this now. I need some time to rebuild the container but its seems the right solution! I think is a bit different for mongo db..